# Get CodeMeter version in inno setup and compare it with a specific version

Tags: inno-setup, pascal

I want to know if CodeMeter is installed and compare it with a specific version.
For that I implemented this function. In my laptop CodeMeter is already installed, but I didn't get its version.

```
function CheckCodeMeterVersion: Boolean;
var
  NodeFileName: string;
  Version : string;
  NodeMS, NodeLS: Cardinal;
  NodeMajorVersion, NodeMinorVersion: Cardinal;
begin
  Result := RegQueryStringValue(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, 'SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\CodeMeter.exe','ImagePath', NodeFileName);
  if Result then
  begin
    MsgBox('ImagePath: ' + NodeFileName, mbInformation, MB_OK);
    Result := GetVersionNumbers(NodeFileName, NodeMS, NodeLS);
    MsgBox('NodeMS: ' + IntToStr(NodeMS), mbInformation, MB_OK);
    MsgBox('NodeLS: ' + IntToStr(NodeLS), mbInformation, MB_OK);
    MsgBox(Format('GetVersionNumbers = %d', [Result]), mbInformation, MB_OK);
    if Result then
    begin
      NodeMajorVersion := NodeMS shr 16; 
      NodeMinorVersion := NodeMS and $FFFF;
      MsgBox('NodeMajorVersion: ' + IntToStr(NodeMajorVersion), mbInformation, MB_OK);
      MsgBox('NodeMinorVersion: ' + IntToStr(NodeMinorVersion), mbInformation, MB_OK);
      if (NodeMajorVersion < 7) then
      begin
       Result := False
      end
      else if(NodeMinorVersion < 10) then 
      begin
          Result := False
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Please can you help me to get the version, because `GetVersionNumbers` always returns false in my code

I used also `GetVersionNumbersString` but I can't get CodeMeter Version.

Comment: Have you checked CodeMeter.exe to confirm it has version information? Not all applications do.

Comment: Sure it have version, I cheked that.

Comment: If `GetVersionNumbers` returns `false`, then your executable file does not contain embedded version metadata.